# Wrong RAM size detected by OS

Tags: linux, windows, memory, bios

I have Thinkpad Edge e430. By default there were one 4GB RAM module installed and I replaced it with two same modules 4GB each.
It has been a while since I did it and now I noticed OSes (Arch Linux and Windows 10, both x64) are showing only 5.7GB available and I don't remember if it was working back then.
BIOS shows 8GB available so I don't see what is the problem. Sorry if this was asked before but I can't find any solution.

dmidecode is showing this:

```
Handle 0x000C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000B
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1600 MHz
        Manufacturer: 859B
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: None
        Part Number: CT51264BF160BJ.M8F
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000B
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1600 MHz
        Manufacturer: 859B
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: None
        Part Number: CT51264BF160BJ.M8F
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
```

PS: BIOS should be up to date

Answer (score 0):

The laptop is most likely allocating the ram as video memory. I don't have access to a computer for searching right now, just using a phone, but Lenovo should have utilities that let you configure how much memory is allocated as video memory.

EDIT:  Well, no thanks for the downvote by someone who doesn't know how laptops work, but the Google term will be "shared video memory".  This is very common.

Based on research so far, it may be configurable by the Intel graphics system tray icon.  It looks like either Device Manager or DirectX diagnostic can get the details of exactly how much  shared memory is configured.

Comment: I would consider this answer helpful if you explained how to verify the memory was being used by video memory and how to disable said configuration.

Comment: At least in older laptops (the kind I have experience with) and desktop systems with shared video memory, the setting for how much RAM is allocated for video is in the BIOS setup, not accessible from the OS.

Comment: I wish I can provide more details, but configuring the amount of shared memory is entirely up to the parties involved (motherboard or graphics manufacture) and is not a standardized feature.  Google how other laptop users change their integrated Intel graphics shared memory may give you some success.